# Data Factory v2: Data Lake incremental copy activity

Tags: sql-server, azure-data-factory, azure-data-lake

Within my **Azure Data Lake** directory `ingest`, I have timestamp-named subdirectories:

```
ingest/1510395023/file.tsv
ingest/1510425023/file.tsv
ingest/1510546210/file.tsv
...
```

In an **Azure Data Factory v2** copy activity (*Data Lake* to *SQL Server*), how can I filter the *Data Lake* directories to those greater than a specified timestamp?

Assume I will record the already-copied timestamps into a *SQL Server*, and on the next pipeline run, I only want to copy incremental new directories based on a *Lookup Activity*.

*Data Factory* documentation references [logical functions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/control-flow-expression-language-functions#logical-functions), but I don't understand how to implement them in this scenario.

**Alternatively**: If a logical comparison filter is available on the file name, as opposed to the directories, that would be helpful as well.

**Note**: I want to load in historical data as well, so only filtering a timestamp greater or equal to `now` is insufficient.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume you have a Data Lake Analytics account.

Using a U-SQL activity, you can copy the targeted files to a single file, which you can then copy using a copy activity.

You can accomplish this by extracting a [file set](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-lake-analytics/u-sql/input-files-u-sql#inputfilesetpath) and filtering it by its virtual column.

Let `@timestamp` string be the input parameter, which was obtained via a lookup activity and which is the latest timestamp that is already processed:

```
@delta = 
    SELECT Col1, Col2 
    FROM(
        EXTRACT 
            [Col1] string,
            [Col2] string,
            [Timestamp] string
        FROM "ingest/{Timestamp}/file.tsv"
        USING Extractors.Tsv(skipFirstNRows : 1/* change if the header is not part of the file*/)
    ) AS T
    WHERE long.Parse([Timestamp]) > long.Parse(@timestamp);


OUTPUT @delta
TO "delta/file.tsv"
USING Outputters.Tsv(outputHeader : true);
```

From there you can copy "delta/file.tsv" to your database.